# Is it safe to drive a motorcycle in Bali without IDP?

Tags: paperwork, driving-licenses, indonesia, motorcycles, bali

I am planning to travel to Bali during the month of July. I have a driving license of India, but I don't have an International Driving Permit. Is it fine to drive a motorcycle in Bali with out it? What are the alternatives that I can look out for in this case?

Comment: Related http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/50221/9395

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Not really**.  Indonesian traffic cops in general and Balinese traffic cops in particular *love* [shaking down motorcycling tourists](http://balimanual.com/dealing-with-the-traffic-police-in-bali/) and not having an IDP means an "instant fine" for you.  Also note that you must have a *motorcycle* license in your home country and an IDP that covers this, an ordinary car license won't do.

Then again, given that you can usually get away for Rp 50,000 (~US$5), if you're only there for a short time you can do the math to figure out which is cheaper.  Rental agencies do not care either way, although any insurance you may have *may* be invalidated if you don't have a valid IDP.

*(And no, I wouldn't usually recommend breaking the law, but if you're a licensed driver with a license in English, this silly insistence on expensive additional pieces of paper is not much short of a scam in itself.)*