# Ride a 125cc scooter in Indonesia if I only have a European car licence?

Tags: driving-licenses, indonesia, eu-citizens, motorcycles, scooters

I have a European car licence. But I don't have any motorcycle licence.

Am I allowed to ride a 125cc scooter in Indonesia?

Comment: Have a search on the website. I'm pretty sure we've had similar questions already.

Comment: @JoErNanO do you mean this http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/44415/9395

Comment: Yes that will work. :)

Comment: On the topic of bribing a policeman in Indonesia http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50271/bribing-indonesian-police-for-missing-motorbike-license/50290

Comment: @JoErNanO maybe you can help http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/52230/9395

Answer (score 3):

Depending on which city you are visiting, generally speaking you can use international driving license (if you have one).

The problem however lies on the human aspect.

1. Local police doesn't really know about this rule
2. They don't speak english that well.
3. They can be bribed...

I know many foreigners riding scooter without proper license in Bali, Lombok or some other small cities, where these rules can be more lenient toward tourists. You can find loads of places where you can rent a scooter for as cheap as $10/day (excl. fuel). Most of them only requires you to hand over a copy of your passport or some refundable deposit.

But if you are planning to explore big cities such as Jakarta, Surabaya, Semarang it is much better if you just rent a car.

Comment: You mean 50'000 rupees per day for a scooter. $10 is 130'000 rupees, which would be a rip off.

Comment: By the way, your answer is interesting but does not help me to find the actual law. Not just what people do and police being bribed, we all know that, it's all over the internet ;)

Comment: @AdrienBe first of all the local currency is Indonesian Rupiah (Rp), i believe Rupees is India. 1 USD = (roughly) Rp.13,000. A quick google search gives me this: https://goo.gl/d0Y5vr

Comment: @AdrienBe you might wanna check this as well: http://www.aaa.com/vacation/idpf.html and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Driving_Permit

Comment: @AdrienBe if you plan to stay for more than 3 months, you might as well apply for a local driving license. It is "easy", if you know what i mean.

Comment: my bad, thanks for correcting me. Yes, 1 US$ is around Rp 13'000. In my experience, the maximum one would pay for a scooter is Rp 75'000, that's why I said paying 10US$ (so around Rp 130'000) would be a rip off.

Comment: The cost to rent a scooter is ~$4 to ~$10 (max). I rent a scooter while ago for as low as $4/day (excl gasoline). It was in Lombok though.

Comment: Thee answer to this question is interesting as well http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/44415/6213

Comment: again, I never heard of someone paying more than 75'000 rupiah per day, regardless of the location in Indonesia. You'd really have to be in a special situation to accept to pay more (special place, or special scooter, or else)

Comment: @AdrienBe, Last time i rented in Jogja, Bali and Nusa Lembongan (i hope i spell it correctly). Oh, be sure you know some local friends they will help you to bargain. I wish i could show you the receipt.

Answer (score -2):

I think it would be best to get in touch with the local department of Indonesian Traffic. Usually it is not allowed as per the country rules but can be applicable if you certify yourself through Indonesian Government Rules. The main reason for not applicable is due to the rules of driving in particular country. Then also it would be best as I said to get in touch with there local department.

Comment: Please contact xxxx is not an answer, is it?