# Get an international driving license in Indonesia

Tags: paperwork, driving-licenses, indonesia, motorcycles, bali

I am in Bali (Indonesia) and I have a Swiss driving license.

Is it possible for me to get an international driving license?

For those wondering: I want an international driving license because Indonesia does not recognize foreign driving licenses.

Comment: As a general rule, it's something best done before you leave your home country...

Answer (score 4):

You have to get the international driving permit from the same country which issued your driver licence. Who issues it varies by country, but it is usually an automobile association or touring club, but can also be issued by a government office.

In the case of Switzerland, you are lucky, as the international driving licence is [issued by your canton's road traffic office](https://www.ch.ch/en/international-driving-licence/), and you can order it by mail. (In most countries I have seen, you can only get one in person.)

Comment: Note that that's not always true, it will depend on which canton you got your driving license from. I got an international driving license from my home canton last year (in person) in the canton of Valais. This was handled not by the canton itself, but delegated to TCS (touring club) and if I wanted to do it by mail, they required me to send in the original driving license, which might be an issue if you're using it. The way of getting the correct information for your canton is following the link you provided and then entering the postal code in the canton where your license was issued.